# Django User-Interests App and its database Model design

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm am building a django app which takes `user Interests` as inputs.

**Now I have 2 Questions -**

1. First is that, what model should I use, should I just add a `field` to `user` model or a separate `Interest Model` and link via `Foreign Key`?
2. I know the former design is bad, and so I.m trying latter one, I'm having a hard time in Django to create Interest Model and its view to save the user interests.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to accomplish the same thing.
Here is how I have solved it:
I have not tried it out yet, but this should work as a solution.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Nation(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Subject(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Interests(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nationals = models.ManyToManyField(Nation)
    subjects = models.ManyToManyField(Subject)
```